# Is there a way to parse XML tags in BigQuery Standard SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have read that it's a [bad idea to parse XML/HTML using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). The alternative suggestion is to use an XML parser. Does one exist in the BigQuery Standard SQL library?

Comment: Can you use a JavaScript UDF? You can probably parse the XML using JavaScript.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Could you explain this a little bit more? If you think that the use a JavaScript UDF is useful, could you please post how to use it as an answer? Thank you.

Comment: This documentation might help:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the documentation to how to use Javascript UDFs in BigQuery like Elliot has mentioned.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

I imagine the UDF might look something like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION XML(x STRING)
RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  var data = fromXML(x);
  return data.title;
"""
OPTIONS(
library="gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/from-xml.min.js"
);
SELECT XML(a) FROM UNNEST(["<title>Title of Page</title>"]) as a
```

Where from-xml.min.js is from [this](https://github.com/kawanet/from-xml) library and loaded into your gcs account